# Just realized I have msvc++ 2008 redistributable package installed.Why and when?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, visual-studio-2008

In my windows xp, why suddenly I have msvc++ 2008 redistributable package installed?

THe installation date is the same as my qt sdk and virtualbox. Is it possible 
because of either ? Or anything else?

Comment: A lot of stuff requires the MSVC++ 2008 redistributable. That's why it's redistributable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt sdk doesnot require Visual C++ 2008 redistributable.

It is required for "applications" developed with Visual C++ SP1, to run on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2008 SP1 installed.
So usually when an application developed with VS is deployed ,they bundle redistributable with the installer.

So my answer would be Virtual Box

Answer (score 1):

From [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en):

> **The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1
>   Redistributable Package (x86) installs
>   runtime components of Visual C++
>   Libraries required to run applications
>   developed with Visual C++ SP1 on a
>   computer that does not have Visual C++
>   2008 SP1 installed.**
>
> This package installs runtime
>   components of C Runtime (CRT),
>   Standard C++, ATL, MFC, OpenMP and
>   MSDIA libraries. For libraries that
>   support side-by-side deployment model
>   (CRT, SCL, ATL, MFC, OpenMP) they are
>   installed into the native assembly
>   cache, also called WinSxS folder, on
>   versions of Windows operating system
>   that support side-by-side assemblies.

Since VirtualBox requires Visual Studio 2003 or 2005 for the [build instructions](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Windows%20build%20instructions), I'm assuming they are from VirtualBox.

Comment: Since is build using VS , its safe to guess that the redistributable came from the installer of Virtual Box

Answer (score 0):

MSVC++ is the [Visual C++ 2008 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en), and my guess is that it was installed with either the Qt SDK or VirtualBox.